# Creating openshift application using OC Client

Tags: openshift

My question is quite simple, Can’t we create an openshift application using OC client from local if we don’t have a git reference to our local code base? If so, why is that ?

Comment: Without a git repo, things become more difficult for a developer, just in general! However, it _is_ still possible. You should be able to still do an `oc new-app` call, although you'll need to manually add the builder image option. Then you can use `oc start-build <build name> --from-dir=.` to upload your local directory as the build input.

Comment: Generally when you build an application in openshift ,for example say your source code is in GitHub ,now the openshift kubernetes need to clone the repo in order to build,that means openshift has to communicate to GitHub that means a certificate of token must be there in openshift to clone the repo. Else if you want to build an image on your local and push to openshift to build it.